# Redirecting to dashboard if props are not received

Tags: reactjs, redirect, routes, react-router-v4

I'm moving to a destination route by clicking on a React Link Component. In the Link, I specify the id of the data that need to fetched in the destination in the 'to' prop. There isn't any problem if the user clicks the Link and reaches the destination. But if the user directly enter the destination route in the browser, since the id is not passed, this error is thrown.

> Cannot read property 'lessonplan_id' of undefined

the error occurs in constructor in the assignment of lessonplan_id

```
this.state = {
            currSlide:0,
            slides: [],
            lessonplan_id: this.props.location.state.lessonplan_id
        }
```

I tried catching the error and using Redirect. But it doesn't seem to work. How can I automatically redirect to the dashboard if the props are not receieved?

Comment: you cannot set initial state using props

Comment: I have a component which renders a particular object in a collection and the object to render depends on the Link pressed in the outer component. If setting initial state by passing id of the object as the props is not recommended, what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have defined your route in the following way in the `index.js` or whatever file you may be using for routes,

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <HashRouter>
        <Route
            path="/lessonplan/:lessonplan_id"
            component={LessonPlanComponent}
        />            
    </HashRouter>
)
```

You can get the `lessonplan_id` in the `LessonPlanComponent` like,

```
this.props.match.params.lessonplan_id
```

It works no matter how you reach the component.

Comment: Thanks very much. It helped me :)

Comment: Good to know, I'm glad :)